# Why are there two mature sequences of microRNAs in miRBase entries?

Tags: genetics, microrna

In the [miRBase database](http://www.mirbase.org) entries generally show a stem loop sequence and two mature sequences. For example the entry for hsa-mir-15a gives three sequences: (1) the Stem-loop sequence hsa-mir-15a, (2) Mature sequence hsa-miR-15a-5p, and (3) Mature sequence hsa-miR-15a-3p.
What is the difference between the two mature sequences? Does the stem loop structure divide into two different miRNA species?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is made clear in the [Wikipedia article on microRNAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroRNA), but, yes, there are two possible mature mir species that can be generated from the stem-loop precursor — one from each side of the stem — although most often one greatly predominates.

The diagram in Wikipedia shows the generation of a single miRNA:

[image: MicroRNA generation from pre-mir]

However, the entry mentioned in the question (hsa-mir-15a) shows that although the 5′-stem component (UAGCA…) is most abundant in this case, there is a small amount of the 3′-stem component (CAGGC…).

[image: hsa-mir-15a from mirBase]

In *Drosophila melanogaster* a single stem component (more often from the 3′-stem, but also from the 3′-stem) most frequently predominates, but I have personally found microRNAs in which both components occur in similar amounts (unpublished).