# Relative abundance and action of 5p and 3p microRNAs

Tags: genetics, microrna

I am a beginner in genetic research and am currently conducting a project concerning microRNAs. Let's say we have miR-1-5p. If miR-1-5p is upregulated in a disease, will miR-1-3p always be downregulated in the same disease? Or will it also be upregulated?

In addition, will miR-1-5p and miR-1-3p have any difference in functions? Or will they always target the same target genes and induce the same cascades with the same resulting effects?

I have been reading some sources but keep getting confused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The reason I think you have not received any answer to your question yet is that it is unclear. What precisely is your research project? When you talk about mir-5p being upregulated, are you describing actual RNAseq results or are you just considering a  hypothetical situation with increased transcription of the precursor? You talk about targetting genes, but it is the mRNA that is targetted, answering your second question. See also [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58818/why-are-there-two-mature-sequences-of-micrornas-in-mirbase-entries/58823#58823).

Comment: It's best to think of miRNAs on a case-by-case basis. Canonically, miRNAs are thought of as negative regulators of their mRNA targets via the RISC complex, but some miRNAs can have a protective effect on their targets in some contexts.  As with much of biology, there aren't any hard-and-fast rules concerning miRNA function relative to their target site.